# Drawing colored marbles with constraints

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

In how many ways can one draw 6 marbles (without replacement) from a bag containing 12 yellow, 10 red, 9 blue marbles such that there is at least 1 yellow and no more than 3 red marbles.

I got the answer 669,585 and the way I solved it involves a lot of summations, almost too much to do by hand; I wrote some code to do it. So I wonder if I'm correct.

Here are my calculations (output of the code):

```
12C1 * 10C0 * 9C5 = 12 * 1 * 126 = 1512
12C1 * 10C1 * 9C4 = 12 * 10 * 126 = 15120
12C1 * 10C2 * 9C3 = 12 * 45 * 84 = 45360
12C1 * 10C3 * 9C2 = 12 * 120 * 36 = 51840
12C2 * 10C0 * 9C4 = 66 * 1 * 126 = 8316
12C2 * 10C1 * 9C3 = 66 * 10 * 84 = 55440
12C2 * 10C2 * 9C2 = 66 * 45 * 36 = 106920
12C2 * 10C3 * 9C1 = 66 * 120 * 9 = 71280
12C3 * 10C0 * 9C3 = 220 * 1 * 84 = 18480
12C3 * 10C1 * 9C2 = 220 * 10 * 36 = 79200
12C3 * 10C2 * 9C1 = 220 * 45 * 9 = 89100
12C3 * 10C3 * 9C0 = 220 * 120 * 1 = 26400
12C4 * 10C0 * 9C2 = 495 * 1 * 36 = 17820
12C4 * 10C1 * 9C1 = 495 * 10 * 9 = 44550
12C4 * 10C2 * 9C0 = 495 * 45 * 1 = 22275
12C5 * 10C0 * 9C1 = 792 * 1 * 9 = 7128
12C5 * 10C1 * 9C0 = 792 * 10 * 1 = 7920
12C6 * 10C0 * 9C0 = 924 * 1 * 1 = 924

sum = 669585
```

Is this right or am I missing something? TIA.

Comment: This isn't clear.  Usually in these problems, the balls are indistinguishable save for color.  That is to say, all the yellow ones are interchangeable.  If that's the case, then I'd just go case by case based on the (small) number of red balls.  But the answer will be *much* smaller than you propose.

Comment: @lulu well, one possible answer is 18, which is just the number of lines i'm summing, each of which is one distinct combination of colors in the result. BUT, if the spirit of the question is to calculate the probability then the computation must "imagine" the balls to be distinguishable even if they are not. That's the approach I used to get the 668,585 result. I suspect the latter is correct, because otherwise the total numbers of balls are simply red herrings and not used in the calculations. So I want to check whether my computations in the latter context are correct or not?

Comment: and whether there is an easier way to get to the answer without having to write code as I did

Comment: One way to simplify the computation somewhat is by considering 4 cases for 0, 1, 2, 3 red balls, and for each case count the choice of remaining balls from blue and yellow, then subtract the case of all blue.

Comment: You should edit the question to clearly state that you were considering each marble distinct as you were to find the probability. As your question stands, I would treat the same color marbles indistinguishable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were a $\color{red}{\text{combinatorics}}$ question:

To solve those types of problem the best method is *[generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)* such that

- Generating function of yellows is $$\frac{x(1-x^{12})}{1-x}=x+x^2+...+x^{12}$$
- Generating function of reds is $$\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3$$
- Generating function of blues is $$\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}$$

What you do is just to find the coefficient of $x^{6}$ *[in the expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expanded+form+of+%28x+%281-x%5E12%29%2F%281-x%29%29%28%281-x%5E4%29%2F%281-x%29%29%28%281-x%5E10%29%2F%281-x%29%29)* of $$\bigg(\frac{x(1-x^{12})}{1-x}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}\bigg)$$

So , answer is $18$

However ,it is a $\color{blue}{\text{probability}}$ question :

- Generating function of yellows is $$C(12,1)x +C(12,2)x^2+..+C(12,12)x^{12}=[(1+x)^{12} -1]$$
- Generating function of reds is : $$C(10,0)x^0 +C(10,1)x +C(10,2)x^2 +C(10,3)x^3=1+10x+45x^2 +120x^3$$
- Generating function of blue is : $$C(9,0)+C(9,1)x+..+C(9,9)x^9=(1+x)^9$$

Now , find $$[x^6]\bigg([(1+x)^{12} -1](1+10x+45x^2 +120x^3)(1+x)^9\bigg)$$

*[EXPANSION](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expanded+form+of+%28%281%2Bx%29%5E12+-1%29%281%2Bx%29%5E9+%281%2B10x%2B45x%5E2+%2B120x%5E3%29)*

So , you are right !! Answer is $669,585$

Comment: that's a supercool answer, not least the link to the expansion at Wolfram Alpha, and esp. the generating functions. thanks!

Comment: @user2297550 you are welcome ! I glad to help you..

Comment: Long time no see. Nice and neat (+1) !

Comment: @trueblueanil i glad to hear it from you :)) many thanks...

Answer (score 3):

If it is a combinatorics question:

If $R$ is the number of red marbles drawn, given $0 \leq R \leq 3$, we are looking for number of solution to,

$3 \leq Y + B \leq 6$, where $Y$ and $B$ are number of yellow and blue marbles respectively. But given we must have at least one yellow marble, $Y \ge 1$. Using $Y = y + 1$ where $y \ge 0$,

That is equivalent to number of solutions to $2 \leq y + B \leq 5$

Using stars and bars, that is $~ \displaystyle {5 + 3 - 1 \choose 3 - 1} - {1 + 3 - 1 \choose 3 - 1} = 18$

If your question is related to probability as you mentioned in comments, then what you have done so far to find the numerator is correct. You can simplify your work though -

Number of ways to choose six marbles with *at most* three red marbles

$ \displaystyle = {10 \choose 0} {21 \choose 6} + {10 \choose 1} {21 \choose 5} + {10 \choose 2} {21 \choose 4}+ {10 \choose 3} {21 \choose 3}$

$ = 686679$

Number of ways to choose six marbles with *at most* three red marbles and *no* yellow marbles

$ \displaystyle = {10 \choose 0} {9 \choose 6} + {10 \choose 1} {9 \choose 5} + {10 \choose 2} {9 \choose 4}+ {10 \choose 3} {9 \choose 3}$

$ = 17094$

Number of ways to choose six marbles with *at most* three red marbles and *at least* one yellow marbles

$ = 686679 - 17094 = 669585$

Comment: a most excellent answer! i appreciate the ingenuity in simplifying the steps. i'll think a little before switching the accepted answer (both are great in different ways). in the meanwhile, thank you very much!

Comment: @user2297550 that's alright - which answer you accept is totally your call. you don't have to explain :) I am glad I could help.